# Расширение формулы на новые строки в столбце (arrayformula)

Tags: google-spreadsheet, google-forms

Не могу победить Google таблицы, чтобы моя формула добавлялась на все новые строки и данные из формулы брались из ячеек соответсвующих строк.

Сейчас либо данные берутся строго по формуле из первой строки/

[Ссылка на пример таблицы](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10Mim5nAYbw8L8Z4t_2ioiOb_MWq81qZVugSpQwMvxUc/edit?usp=sharing), в столбце AG  я забил формулу руками, она работает правильно
В столбце AH через массив - не получается.

Comment: Зачем в столбце *AG* проверять диапазон (`IF(AB2:AB="FALSE"`) если это формула для одной строки? В столбце *AH* нужна формула в каждой строке или нужно что-то вычислить в ячейке *AH1*? Вы бы написали, что хотите получить формулой...

Comment: В ячейке AG2 должно отображаться значение формулы для строки 2 -=ЕСЛИ(AB2=ЛОЖЬ;0;ЕСЛИОШИБКА(СЧЁТЕСЛИ(F2:AB2;ИСТИНА)/(СЧЁТЕСЛИ(F2:AB2;ИСТИНА)+СЧЁТЕСЛИ(F2:AB2;ЛОЖЬ));0))

В ячейке AG3 =ЕСЛИ(AB3=ЛОЖЬ,.....) и так далее. т.е. ровно так как в примерной таблице

Comment: Какой смысл в усложнении вычислений? Добавили строки **с запасом**, протянули формулу... В *Excel* есть инструмент *Таблица* (*Умная таблица*). При добавлении строки формулы и форматирование добавляются автоматически. В *Google*-таблицах такого нет.

Comment: И *ЕСЛИОШИБКА*  лишняя. ведь в знаменателе нуля никогда не будет

Comment: Мне кажется, что тут есть смысл, когда мы стараемся уплотнить вычисления, для компактного хранения. Например, последняя колонка отвечает на вопрос "Вы курите?" в опросе о детском питании. Ну, тут само напрашивается вернуть 0.

Comment: `(COUNTIF(F4:AB4;TRUE)+COUNTIF(F4:AB4;FALSE)` - разве здесь может быть ноль? Это количество ячеек в диапазоне, ведь ячейка принимает значение или *ЛОЖЬ*, или *ИСТИНА*. Поэтому фрагмент спокойно можно заменить на константу: `=ЕСЛИ(AB2;СЧЁТЕСЛИ(F2:AB2;ИСТИНА)/23;)`. Если же по каким-то причинам в диапазоне есть пустые ячейки (но не может же строка быть полностью без флажков!): `=ЕСЛИ(AB2;СЧЁТЕСЛИ(F2:AB2;ИСТИНА)/СЧЁТЕСЛИ(F2:AB2;"<>");)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Проблема

Есть формула для каждой строки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Требуется вписать формулу массива, которая будет сама "протягиваться" вниз

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема в том, что формула массива "пытается" просчитать все сразу.

### Решение

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вам нужно использовать матричное умножение, чтобы посчитать "построчный" результат.

На самом деле это предельно очевидно, если знать, что такое умножение матрицы на вектор.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  MMULT(
    (F2:AB)^1;SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(F2:AB);1;1;0)
  )/COLUMNS(F2:AB)
)
```

К сожалению, вся теория сюда никак не поместится,но вы можете ознакомиться с ujhjq примеров [CONTRIBUTORPW. ARRAYFORMULA. Работа с диапазонами и массивами](https://contributor.pw/post/google-sheets-formulas-arrayformula/?source=ruso)

С учетом проверки одной из колонок на TRUE/FALSE

```
={"Solution";ARRAYFORMULA((AB2:AB)^1*
  MMULT(
    (F2:AB)^1;SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(F2:AB);1;1;0))/COLUMNS(F2:AB)
)}
```

Чтобы учесть пустые ячейки `ISBLANK()`, необходимо также их посчитать

```
={"Solution";ARRAYFORMULA((OFFSET(AB:AB;1;0))^1*
  MMULT(
    OFFSET(F:AB;1;0)^1;SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(OFFSET(F:AB;1;0));1;1;0))/
  MMULT(
    NOT(ISBLANK(OFFSET(F:AB;1;0)))^1;SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(OFFSET(F:AB;1;0));1;1;0))
)}
```

[Мое решение](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14mFGQDb1vC3tqkUhNF3kFXCKBkil-BP-O01Y43b0BLA/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Не совсем так. В вашем примере не учитывается значение ячеек AB. По формуле ЕСЛИ(AB=ЛОЖЬ то должен возвращаться 0. Сейчас этого не происходит.
Также у меня были неверно проставлены кавычки в этой формуле - сейчас я исправил.

Comment: Добавил пример, с учетом ваших исправлений

Comment: Обратите внимание, что на скрине наши результаты совпадают https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjF5E.png, так что я не мог знать наверняка, зачем там эта проверка.